# How to copy Content linked files to project directory without causing duplicates

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to reference some javascript files in my project that are coming from a nuget package. So i added these files as a Content Link reference.

```
<Content Include="$(NuGetPath_jQuery)\Content\Scripts\**\*.*">
  <Link>Scripts\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

But that I can F5 debug the web project, I need these files to be a part of the project folder structure. I am also using these files in a ScriptBundle so the physical directory structure needs to be present for locally debugging. As a result, I ended up adding the following build ttask that copies the content linked files as per [Matt Perdeck's blog](http://mattperdeck.com/post/Copying-linked-content-files-at-each-build-using-MSBuild.aspx) which is referenced in a lot of other threads around content linking as per below.

```
<Target Name="CopyLinkedContentFiles" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Copy SourceFiles="%(Content.Identity)" 
          DestinationFiles="%(Content.Link)" 
          SkipUnchangedFiles='true' 
          OverwriteReadOnlyFiles='true' 
          Condition="'%(Content.Link)' != ''" />
</Target>
```

Now VS is happy while F5 debugging. But complains on loading the project the next time about not being able to add the content links because the files already exist. Which were copied in the previous build. Am I missing some secret sauce to tell VS to ignore these warnings? I noticed that msbuild does not throw any such warning. It is only VS that is complaining. I see warnin  like below :

*Warning        The file 'C:\Users\pkorhale.nuget\packages\jquery\3.3.1\Content\Scripts\jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js' could not be added to the project.  Cannot add a link to the file jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js. There is already a file of the same name in this folder.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out, that I needed to turn off the visibility for this content. Anyways the file gets copied over physically so we end up seeing it in the solution explorer after the first build. Which was good enough for me.

```
<Content Include="$(NuGetPath_jQuery)\Content\Scripts\**\*.*">
  <Link>Scripts\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  <Visible>false</Visible>
</Content>
```